# Position Fixed in CSS within a bounding box?

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I have a comment box like so...

```
<div id="comments">
   ...
</div>
```

Now, inside this comments div I have another div called box...

```
<div id="comments">
   <div id="box">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

The box div is position: fixed and it works mostly fine, but...

What I would like is, instead of the box div "floating" above all the content, for it
to be only scrollable within the comment div.

Do i need to use JavaScript for this?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "only scrollable within the comment div"? Also, "floating" means something very specific in CSS, and it's not what you mean. When you say "floating", are you refering to #box appearing in front of other content?

Comment: Sure, when you position: fixed an element, it does this: http://www.bluelounge.com/index.php (scroll down the page). I would like this functionality but only to happen within a div (not the entire page) - hope that makes sense

Comment: @antony.trupe no, it doesn't.   The community has spoken, SO is a perfectly valid place for HTML/CSS questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14637/close-as-belongs-on-doctype

Comment: you could try http://doctype.com ; it really depends how much of your question is visual/pixels versus ascii/code.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14906/do-css-questions-belong-on-so-or-doctype/14908#14908, and "What kind of questions should I not ask here?...web design and HTML/CSS layout", from the faq.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JS for this. Simply add overflow:scroll and set the outer DIV to the fixed size. Then if internal DIV is larger than outer div you will see the scrollbar(s)

You can try it [on this page](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    #comments { overflow: auto; height: 200px; }
</style>

<div id="comments">
   <div id="box">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Give a suitable height for the container div ( comments ) and oveflow auto will make a scroll bar if the content exceeds the height of the container.

[Overflow: the 'overflow' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow)